# How to enable client side debug printout

Tags: quickfix

I installed the latest quickfix on a virtual machine environment, it does not work properly. Here is what I found:

```
1. At server side I run run_executor_python.sh
2. At client side I run run_tradeclient.sh
```

Server side does not receive anything - I know this because if it does, it prints out the received message.

I modified cfg/tradeclient.cfg and set the SocketConnectHost to 127.0.0.1 and start server at the same VM, this time I can see the server receives messages. So this means my installation is good.

I am wondering if there is some command option I can set so that clientside can print out some status or error message which can help me trace where the problem is. I tried run "./tradeclient -h", but "-h" is not a valid option.

My colleague did the same setup as I did and it worked for me, the only difference is his is on real machines, instead of virtual machines. Do you know if there is known problem on VM? Google does not return anything.

Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm thinking you have a firewall or other security thing blocking your connection.

Comment: Are you sure you've configured your VM network devices so they can communicate with each other?

Comment: I can ping each other VM, so the network connection is all right, I believe. I am looking at firewall setup. Again, if there is any trick to turn on debug printout, if there is any, please share.